# ONSEN UI Removing default styles from list-item

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

How can I remove default padding from list-item because the list-item looks too large.

Comment: Check this new modifier for ons-list-item that has been implemented in Onsen UI 1.3.3-dev: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/commit/2df29e240f1a2e5a98c0cff3b01a11a659f340fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change min-height with a modifier and css !